# How can I subtract two row's within same column in same date?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a query. I want to do an subtraction of the first and last row in the same day. I wrote the this query, but I was not sure of the performance. Is there an alternative way to this problem?

```
| imei  |    date                 | km    |
|-----------------------------------------|
| 123   | 2019-01-15 00:00:01     | 15    |
| 123   | 2019-01-15 12:12:08     | 8     |
| 123   | 2019-01-15 23:00:59     | 30    |
| 456   | 2019-01-15 00:03:12     | 232   |
| 456   | 2019-01-15 07:04:00     | 123   |
| 456   | 2019-01-15 23:16:18     | 464   |
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
gg.imei,
DATE_FORMAT(gg.datee, '%Y-%m-%d'),
gg.km - (SELECT 
        g.km
    FROM
        gps g
    WHERE
        g.datee LIKE '2019-01-15%'
            AND g.datee = (SELECT 
                MIN(t.datee)
            FROM
                gps t
            WHERE
                t.datee LIKE '2019-01-15%'
                    AND t.imei = g.imei)
            AND g.imei = gg.imei
    GROUP BY g.imei) AS km
FROM
    gps gg
WHERE
gg.datee LIKE '2019-01-15%'
    AND gg.datee = (SELECT 
        MAX(ts.datee)
    FROM
        gps ts
    WHERE
        ts.datee LIKE '2019-01-15%'
            AND gg.imei = ts.imei)
```

Result is true.

```
| imei    |    date    | km    |
|------------------------------|
| 123     | 2019-01-15 | 15    |
| 456     | 2019-01-15 | 232   |
```

But the query is too complicated.

Edit: There are 3 million records in the table.

Comment: If the earliest result is always the one with the lowest value, and the latest is always the one with the highest value (as per your sample data), then the solution is trivial. Otherwise it's a little trickier

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: Iam on mine mobile so i might see it wrong because of the SQL format.. but it looks like you are using group by in a invalid way. using column in the select which is not in the group by clause. Which can cause invalid results in MySQL so i doubt your current result Is even valid to begin with

Comment: Please, don't used reserved words like `date` as column names, it just makes horrible code to read.  Equally, if the column also includes a time component, the name is misleading, use `date_time` or something even more clear such as `date_time_gps_device_polled`

Comment: I have translated into English to make it more understandable. Thanks for the suggestion. @MatBailie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find first and last datetime for each imei-date pair in a sub query then join with it:

```
SELECT agg.imei, agg.date_date, gps_last.km - gps_frst.km AS diff
FROM (
    SELECT imei, DATE(date) AS date_date, MIN(date) AS date_frst, MAX(date) AS date_last
    FROM gps
    GROUP BY imei, DATE(date)
) AS agg
JOIN gps AS gps_frst ON agg.imei = gps_frst.imei AND agg.date_frst = gps_frst.date
JOIN gps AS gps_last ON agg.imei = gps_last.imei AND agg.date_last = gps_last.date
```

You need appropriate indexes on your table though. The `DATE(date)` part in particular will be slow, so you might want to consider adding another column for storing the date part only.

Comment: Before You edited the post I execute the query and it was very slow. I thought about adding index and now the problem is solved. Thank you so much.

Comment: I like `frst`, the level of anal attention to detail that you want to make everything line up nicely.  Just, Like, Me :)